# 1c bitrix редактирование формы

Tags: php, html, битрикс, битрикс24

где найти код формы и дописать его? проект установлен с готового решения.

Answer (score 0):

Воспользуйтесь "Эрмитажем". Войдите в панель администратора, перейтте на нужную Вам страницу с формой, далее в верхнем правом углу сможете найти переключатель.

[image: Эрмитаж в битриксе]

Далее, наведите мышкой на форму, в верхнем левом углу появится шестеренка и выпадающий список, там сможете найти шаблон, который используется для вывода формы и отредактировать так, как Вам это необходимо.

Более подробная информация про "Эрмитаж": https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?bitrix_include_areas=N&COURSE_ID=1&CHAPTER_ID=628 (обратите особое внимание на раздел "Режим правки").